# Function returning 1 instead of the reverse of the Number

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

Hey I have this function in python3 , can anyone explain why it is giving 1 as output instead of the number as reverse

```
def reverse(a , rev):
    if a > 0:
        d =  a % 10
        rev = (rev * 10) + d
        reverse(a/10 , rev)

    return rev

b = input("Enter the Number")
x = reverse(b , 0)
print(x)
```

Comment: You are ignoring the recursion call result. It's not clear to me how your approach would work recursively.

Comment: Unclear why. We don't know what you entered

Comment: Consider it not recursion , my colleague send me this code and I can't figure why it does not work. It returns 1 whatever I enter.

Comment: It is definitely recursion. You call reverse in itself. If it's your friend's code, as them how it works

Comment: @AswinMohan: did you ask your friend then as to how it is supposed to work? It doesn't work, because the recursive call results are ignored.

Answer (score 3):

You need to:

- use integer division (`//`)
- capture the value returned from the recursive call, and `return` it
- convert the string input to number (`int()`)

Corrected script:

```
def reverse(a, rev):
    if a > 0:
        d =  a % 10
        rev = (rev * 10) + d
        return reverse(a//10, rev)

    return rev

b = input("Enter the Number")
x = reverse(int(b), 0)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're doing it like that. Seems like the following is easier

```
def rev(a):
   return int(str(a)[::-1])
```

Anyway, I believe you should use "//" instead of "/" for dividing without the rest in python 3?